# Send value from activity to Broadcast class

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-broadcast

I want to send a string value from Main_activity to Broadcast receiver class. I try to use `send Broadcast()` function but my alarm works immediately not works after time.

How can I do that please?

Comment: Is this a broadcast explicitly register on the manifest? it should be as easy as calling [Context#sendBroadcast(intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent))

Answer (score 0):

Passing value from activity to BroadcastReceiver do the following things:

In your Main_activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main_activity.this, NameofBroadcastReceiver.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("key", "value");
i.putExtras(b);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

And in your BroadCastReceiver class,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String result = intent.getString("key");
    // your method
}
```

If you want to use AlaramManger to invoke Receiver at certain time follow the tutorial provided [here](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/). It might help you to implement AlaramManager for your Receiver.